# How to solve "page not found" page title when using query_var in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my `index.php` file. Everything is great on page 1, but when I click on page 2, the page title shows "Page not found.". There's no issue in lading the posts, just `wp_title()` shows `"not found"` as title. How should I solve the issue?

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged' => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

get_header(); 


...


<?php 
      the_posts_pagination();
      $pagination = paginate_links(
        array(
          'base' => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
          'format' => '?paged=%#%',
          'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
          'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
          'prev_next' => false,
          'type' => 'array',
        )
      );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $pagination ) : ?>
        <?php foreach ( $pagination as $link ) : ?>
            <?php echo $link ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

?>
```